nextjs 15 behind load balancer and 2 vms with a build
My setup is the following , I have two vms in different data centers and for each I use the typical commands of pnpm build and pnpm start to start the production server in NextJS 15. I have a form which calls a server action to log in users, I use the library next-auth@v5 with the credentials provider for authentication. If I hit the ip:port of each individual to log in everything goes fine, but i try to login by using the domain name of the load balancer , the server action gives me this error:
Error: Failed to find Server Action "6013efdf52edfe1187db4470fede217a4b44bbe9ae". This request might be from an older or newer deployment. Original error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'workers')
    at rf (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:127:2692)
    at <unknown> (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:127:1184)
    at async rd (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:126:11787)
    at async n7 (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:132:1237)
    at async doRender (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1587:34)
    at async responseGenerator (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1834:28)
    at async NextNodeServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1876:28)
    at async NextNodeServer.renderPageComponent (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2290:24)
    at async NextNodeServer.renderToResponseImpl (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2328:32)
Error: Failed to find Server Action "6013efdf52edfe1187db4470fede217a4b44bbe9ae". This request might be from an older or newer deployment. Original error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'workers')
    at rf (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:127:2692)
    at <unknown> (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:127:1184)
    at async rd (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:126:11787)
    at async n7 (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:132:1237)
    at async doRender (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1587:34)
    at async responseGenerator (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1834:28)
    at async NextNodeServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1876:28)
    at async NextNodeServer.renderPageComponent (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2290:24)
    at async NextNodeServer.renderToResponseImpl (/opt/evg/data_mount/next/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_@babel+core@7.26.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824_xelwhe2z5lglznkjbudtglu7em/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2328:32)

I dont know what is going on here, read in some articles,issues,reports that server action must come from a single build, but how do i configure then my 2 vms to have the same build when use the command pnpm build in both vms ? I tried editting my next.config.ts file like this:
import type { NextConfig } from "next";

const nextConfig: NextConfig = {
  /* config options here */
  generateBuildId:  async () => {
    // This could be anything, using the latest git hash
    return process.env.GIT_HASH || null
  },
  headers: async ()=> {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
            value: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL || ''
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

First i tried using generatebuildId, that didnt work, then i tried using headers, that did also not work.
